# What are the units of distance in the MiXiM based Veins simulation scenarios?

Tags: omnet++, veins

Hello StackEx community.

I am running a scenario in `Veins 3.0` where I am using the `commandDistanceRequest()`function to find out the distance between two nodes. I am getting values which, I suppose, is in the domain of the `MiXiM` - `OMNeT++` simulation play-field.

My questions here are:

1. What is the unit of this distance returned by `commandDistanceRequest()`?
2. I know that `OMNeT++` and `SUMO` use different sets of coordinate spaces. Is it different for both of them or only the coordinate space differs here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The unit returned by the `commandDistanceRequest()` is in `m` (meters)

> [Link:](http://www.physicalgeography.net/fundamentals/2b.html) Two types of coordinate systems are currently in general use in
>   geography: the geographical coordinate system and the rectangular
>   (also called Cartesian) coordinate system.

2. SUMO and OMNeT++ use *Cartesian* coordinates both. However in SUMO the `y` axis is flipped and there is an offset.

Comment: So you mean that this Cartesian coordinate system is based on the `m` meter unit, right?
And thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: yes, the distance is given in meters and the speed in meters per second